# jquery - prev button {display:none} in default and next button will {display:none} in last

Tags: jquery

I have basic knowledge on `jquery` so can somebody guide me if this posible `pre button` will `display:none` in default and the `next button` also `display:none` in the last

js:

```
$('div.section').first();

$('a.display').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

      var t = $(this).text(),
      that = $(this);

    if (t === 'next' && $('.current').next('div.section').length > 0) {
        var $next = $('.current').next('.section');
        var top = $next.offset().top;

        $('.current').removeClass('current');     
        $(function () {
               $next.addClass('current');
               $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: $('.current').offset().top }, 'slow');

        });
  } else if (t === 'prev' && $('.current').prev('div.section').length > 0) {
        var $prev = $('.current').prev('.section');
        var top = $prev.offset().top;

        $('.current').removeClass('current');

        $(function () {
               $prev.addClass('current');
               $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: $('.current').offset().top }, 'slow');
        });
  } 
});
```

and here's the [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/jhunlio/s5g8K/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do it for you. Let me know how it works out.

```
function hideShowLinks() {
    $('.section').each(function (k, v) {
        var self = $(this);
        if (self.hasClass('current')) {
            if (k == 0) {
                $('#display1').hide();
                $('#display').show();
            } else if (k == ($('.section').length - 1)) {
                $('#display').hide();
                $('#display1').show();
            } else {
                $('#display, #display1').show();
            }
        }
    });
}

hideShowLinks();

$(window).scroll(function () {
    hideShowLinks();
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tomanow/s5g8K/3/)

Comment: yes you can use `.fadeOut('slow')` and `.fadeIn('slow')` in place of `.hide()` and `.show()`